# How to select an expandable folder when saving?

Tags: mutt, imap

I have IMAP folders like this:

```
A
A/A
A/B
B
B/A
C
```

When I save (<kbd>s</kbd> in mutt) a mail and use <kbd>?</kbd>, I'm presented with a view like this:

```
A +
B +
C
```

It works perfectly until I want to move to `A` or `B`. If I click on `A`, it automatically expands `A` and presents me with its children (`A` and `B`).

Is there a way to do that? Or is there a way to write it without using the <kbd>?</kbd> view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the <kbd>?</kbd> view, you can cursor to the folder you want to pick and press <kbd>Space</kbd>.

If you're in a place where you can just type the name (e.g. in the plain <kbd>s</kbd> view), you can just type the name of the folder preceded by <kbd>=</kbd>.